# Плагин-виджет: кто онлайн

Tags: ajax, php

Всегда задавался вопросом, как сделать такой виджет для сайта. У меня один есть на PHP,
но он отслеживает, когда пользователь что-нибудь нажимает на сайте. А как сделать так, чтоб он отслеживал, даже если просто человек висит на сайте?

Comment: Как вариант - отправлять ajax запрос каждые, например 30 секунд, скрипту, который выполняет функции счётчика пользователей.

Comment: ну а если он не кликает никуда его ж сайт то не увидит

Comment: AJAX сам по таймеру совершает запросы (если открыта страница).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать аякс запрос с клиента на сервер(при загрузке и потом каждую минуту или чаще), типа я в сети. Сохранять на сервере время этого запроса. А виджет будет проверять, данные от каких пользователей пришли за последнюю минуту.

Comment: можно просто какой-нибудь мини скрипт по этому поводу

Comment: @MaximPro, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: ок.........

Comment: Если на сайте одновременно большое количество пользователей онлайн то вариант с ajax запросами не самый оптимальный, это будет создавать дополнительную нагрузку на сервер. Для этих случаем лучше подходит Websockets или Long Polling когда висит дополнительное постоянное соединение и данные можно отправить клиенту в тот же момент когда произошло событие на сервере без дополнительных запросов.